# is it possible to predict timeseries data with zelig package

Tags: r, r-zelig

I am trying to use zelig r package to do some predictive and simulated graphs:

```
dput(x)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14640, 14668, 14699, 14729, 
14760, 14790, 14821, 14852, 14882, 14913, 14943, 14974, 15005, 
15033, 15064, 15094, 15125, 15155, 15186, 15217, 15247, 15278, 
15308, 15339, 15370, 15399, 15430, 15460, 15491, 15521, 15551, 
15582, 15611), class = "Date"), Records = c(44560938, 40227158, 
46674885, 45379535, 47051792, 51301979, 47659151, 50002855, 47952955, 
49681927, 51569764, 58513754, 62200793, 54645673, 61465915, 57829119, 
58410815, 64874812, 59066293, 71056318, 67101651, 62214988, 63183320, 
66750198, 61483322, 67546775, 75290893, 60713372, 77879142, 70290302, 
83201853, 83837301, 68110825)), .Names = c("Date", "Records"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
33L))
```

When I do this:

```
z.out1 <- zelig(Records~Date, model = "logit", data = x)
```

I get all these errors:

```
The following object(s) are masked from 'env (position 4)':

    ..., data, formula, robust, w, weights
The following object(s) are masked from 'env (position 6)':

    ..., data, formula, robust, w, weights
The following object(s) are masked from 'env (position 8)':

    ..., data, formula, robust, w, weights
The following object(s) are masked from 'env (position 10)':

    ..., data, formula, robust, w, weights
The following object(s) are masked from 'env (position 12)':

    ..., data, formula, robust, w, weights
The following object(s) are masked from 'd.f (position 4)':

    Date, Records
The following object(s) are masked from 'd.f (position 6)':

    Date, Records
The following object(s) are masked from 'd.f (position 8)':

    Date, Records
The following object(s) are masked from 'd.f (position 10)':

    Date, Records
The following object(s) are masked from 'd.f (position 12)':

    Date, Records
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

has anyone used zelig with timeseries data?

Comment: Go [here](http://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/zelig.pdf).  Hit ctrl + f. search for "time series".  Hope that helps.  Also, the homepage for the package (http://gking.harvard.edu/zelig) says "Please send **All** questions, bugs and requests: Zelig Mailing List" (emphasis theirs).  I wouldn't mention it if they hadn't put it in bold.

Comment: Why do you want to do your time series analysis in zelig? The task view (http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/web/views/TimeSeries.html) lists lots of dedicated packages for time series analysis, but zelig is not among them.